# Should I use SSIS or the SQL Server Import Export tool for a large bulk insert operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, import, ssis

I will soon need to import millions of records into into a single SQL Server Database table which we use in production. The data to import will be available in the form of about 40 csv files, each having hundreds of thousands of records.

For each row, some of the column values are supplied by the csv files, whereas other rows will require values that I must specify.

I am trying to determine which tool to use.  I noticed that SQL Server Management Studio comes with the Import Export Wizard.  Is that tool advisable for this type of job?  Or should I use SSIS instead?

Some other questions I have:

- Should I "lock" the table during the operation?
- Should I perform the insert into a copy of the production table and
  then once the operation is validated, should I make the copy the
  official version of the production table?

Comment: the import/export wizard will generate a small SIS-Package which can be even saved after clicking together ... so there will be no difference while importing

Comment: but the main draw-back of the wizard: it is executed on the client, introducing a lot of latency (workstation->server) ... executing as SIS on the server directly will outperform massively

Comment: I would recommend that you sanitize and collapse this data before importing.

Comment: Use SSIS, it's built for exactly this kind of thing. You can configure the destination to lock during the operation, commit in batches, etc etc. Whether you should commit directly to your production table is a very opinion based question, depending on all of the details of your particular situation. Stackoverflow won't really be able to answer this.

Comment: Please note that SQL Server does not handle true CSV files (with all complexities) at least in earlier versions. Re "what tool to use": if it is once-off import with no time constraints, then I suggest you use Import-Export wizard as it is quicker to get it to work. Otherwise go SSIS approach.
Re "I perform the insert into a copy of the production table": as you state that "other rows will require values that I must specify", I suggest a separate table(s) for import and post processing. Once you get all the data loaded, validated and post processed you can copy it to your destination table.

Comment: `For somerows, some values you will be supplying`. It looks that you cannot use import export wizard with some custom logic. Better go with SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you are having some logic to handle for the rows from CSV (some rows, you will insert and some rows require you to supply some values), you cannot have these kinds of logic in the Import Export Wizard. It is straightforward load. So, you have to go for SSIS only.
   You need to have conditional branching to split the rows and supply values to the target table.
2. For the second question, If possible, I would suggest you to load to separate table and then rename them later. That way, production system users are not impacted by this loading.